# DocumentDB: How to verify which indexes were used?

Tags: azure, indexing, azure-cosmosdb, sql-execution-plan

Even if you have designed your document schema with care and handcrafted minimal necessary indexes toward good balance of read vs change scenarios, it may not always be intuitive which index is actually doing the job for a heavy-RU query and if the choices are what you expected it to be. Or maybe there's a typo in indexing policy in a critical property name, causing a silent fall-back to some unsuitable index required by some other query..

I know that I can use the following tools to debug index usage in DocumentDB:

- `RequestCharge` usage per query, but it does not say where this RU is spent on.
- time/count metrics using [`x-ms-documentdb-populatequerymetrics`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/documentdb-sql-query-metrics#query-execution-metrics) header, which is useful and hints that "some" index was used, but not which one(s) were actually used.

The problem is the above toolset still forces blind experiments and working on unverifiable assumptions, causing query/index optimization to be a time-consuming process.

In SQL Server you could simply fetch the execution plan and verify index design and usage correctness. **Is there a analogous tool for DocumentDB?**

An illustrative pseudo-example of a query when it is not obvious which index(es) DocDB would pick:

```
select s.poorlySelectiveIndexed
from c
join s in c.sub
where c.anotherPoorlySelectiveIndexed = @aCommonValue
   and s.Indexed1 in ('a', 'b', 'c') 
   and ARRAY_CONTAINS(s.Indexed2, @searchValue)
   and ARRAY_CONTAINS(s.Indexed3, 'literalValue')
   and (s.SuperSelective ='23456' OR c.AnotherSuperSelective = '76543') 
order by s.RangeIndexed4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the documentDB team is considering the already mentioned `x-ms-documentdb-populatequerymetrics` header and it's corresponding response as such a tool.

As mentioned in [this response from "Azure Cosmos DB Team" in Azure feedback site](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/15959218-provide-constructs-to-look-at-the-query-execution) from August 27, 2017:

> We’re pleased to announce the availability of query execution statistics: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/documentdb-sql-query-metrics#query-execution-metrics
>
> Using these metrics, **you can infer the execution plan and tune the query and index for best performance tradeoffs**.

Currently it does not seem to officially expose detailed information about used indexes, but let's hope it will change in some future version.